# What is the relation between size, margins and padding of a groupBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Trying to get my head around layout in XAML.

The term "size" of a control confuses me: It could be interpreted as the space the control takes on the screen or as the size of the control independent of any screen. Even if 'Size=Width x Height'.

So: Does the "size" of a groupBox include the margins?
Does the "size" of a groupBox include the padding?
The "upper left" corner of the groupBox is the upper left of the outer margins, or of the padding?

Comment: Wow.  Lazy much?  Experiment a little.  Learn by doing, grasshopper!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 3):

The size doesn't include margins but just paddings and so the origin (your upper left corner). They have the same meaning whatever framework you will use and *usually* by default they're set to `0` or `None`.

[image]

*<sub>Image from [www.addedbytes.com](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/the-box-model-for-beginners/)</sub>*

Answer (score 2):

> The Margin property defines the space around the control that keeps
>   other controls a specified distance from the control's borders.
>
> The Padding property defines the space in the interior of a control
>   that keeps the control's content (for example, the value of its Text
>   property) a specified distance from the control's borders.
>
> The following illustration shows the Padding and Margin properties on
>   a control.
>   [image]

and size (width, height) is borders of the `GroupBox` itself.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229627(v=vs.110).aspx)